# Raspberry Pi cannot connect to network and throws host error on sudo apt install

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52cL.jpg

My Raspberry Pi can't access anything. I have a wireless LAN adapter, keyboard, monitor and SD card in it.

I can't install, update or upgrade. I even tried to find a way without directly running a command and force manually install these tools, but I couldn't find any other way to download these files and install them. I don't know how to fetch these and install these.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! How is your Raspberry Pi connected to the network? Are you trying to use wireless LAN? How have you set it up?

Comment: I have set up everything, I have every stuff required and settings. I do not know why is this issue happening as there is no config file for internet settings. these errors are what I get, there is no internet connection and I cannot set the connection because I cannot install any network connection related items.

Comment: There is no `/etc/network/interfaces` file, for example? Please provide information about the particular steps you have done. Is there any guide you were following? Please add a link. The information you have provided does not allow us to identify your problem unfortunately.

Comment: I just read the documentation and other stack exchange sites, and followed the command guide. Installations and others were used a program I originally had before. Nothing much about the guides. also I do not have the etc folder at all, I have 1 folder called overlays. didnt edit other files. The program I used is called balenaEtcher